# Subtracting two dates in Python

Tags: python, date

I would like to subtract two dates

i.e I have entered a date into a textbox which is of type `String`
like below

```
type(waitForObject(":VWAP Calculator_LCDateTextField"), "07/24/14")
```

I am capturing that date like below

```
Current = (waitForObject(":VWAP Calculator_LCDateTextField").text)
```

so, now I want to subtract the captured date with my current system date and get the difference in days. I tried many ways and see no success. Someone please help with this as soon as possible.

P.S: I have python 2.4 and 2.7

Comment: Can you use either 2.4 or 2.7, or do you have a preference? I imagine the answers could be different depending on which one it is.

Comment: You should look at the `datetime` module, specifically the section about `timedeltas`.  What you're after is _built in_ functionality in Python.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense it's Python 2.7

Comment: @g.d.d.c I have gone through that module and tried many ways but I always run into issues. Please suggest me

Comment: @eswar - If you have already tried some things, please include that information in your question. Describe what you've tried and how it failed. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TheSoundDefense: I get this error"Detail TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'time.struct_time' " when I followed the Alex solution

Comment: @eswar it sounds like you're getting a `time` object for the current time instead of `datetime`. They both need to be `datetime` for subtraction to work.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> x = datetime.strptime("07/24/14", "%m/%d/%y")
>>> y = datetime.strptime("07/30/14", "%m/%d/%y")
>>> x-y
datetime.timedelta(-6)
>>> (x-y).days
-6
```

This uses the datetime.strptime method of converting a string to a datetime object. Then you can simply do arithmetic on datetime objects. The result will be in a timedelta (basically a difference of time) which you can then call `.days` on if you want the difference to be in days. You can read about all these functions [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

If you want to get current date using these methods, it's as simple as:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 31, 12, 16, 12, 966428)
```

And it returns another datetime object which you can then perform the date arithmetic on.

Comment: I want to subtract the entered date in textbox with the system date Alex.

Comment: @eswar there's no way you can do that without converting your string to something else. Alex's answer gives what is probably the easiest method of doing so.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense:I have converted the string into datetype below Current = datetime.Parse(waitForObject(":VWAP Calculator_LCDateTextField").text)
dt1 = (waitForObject(":VWAP Calculator_LCDateTextField").text)      
entereddate =datetime.strftime(dt1, "%Y/%m/%d")                      how do I proceed from here

Comment: @eswar get the current `datetime`, as Alex showed above, and then subtract and get the number of days, which he also showed above.

Comment: Is this below code correct.                                              Current = datetime.Parse(waitForObject(":VWAPCalculator_LCDateTextField").text)
        dt1 = (waitForObject(":VWAP Calculator_LCDateTextField").text)
        entereddate =datetime.strftime(dt1, "%Y/%m/%d")
        
        dt2= datetime.now()
        dt2.dt1

Comment: AFter getting the days. How do we convert it into a string value./

Comment: str(days) will turn the integer into a string

Answer (score 0):

1. Parse the string to `datetime` objects ([Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime))
2. Subtract the `datetime` objects, you'll get a `timedelta` object which has `days` property

```
delta = dtend - dtstart
print delta.days
```

Comment: I have tried this                            Current = datetime.Parse(waitForObject(":VWAP Calculator_LCDateTextField").text)
        dt1 = (waitForObject(":VWAP Calculator_LCDateTextField").text)
       entereddate =datetime.strftime(dt1, "%Y/%m/%d")

Comment: How do I proceed from here